# Changing image color based on CSS stylesheet

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I have `ImageView` which I want the image to change its color based on a global CSS property in a stylesheet attached to the `Scene`.

```
.root
{
    theme-image-color: red;
}
```

I already have a utility method that can change the color.

```
public static final Image changeImageColor(Image originalImage, Color desiredColor)
```

This method returns a new instance of `Image` with the desired color. It is implemented using `WritableImage`, `PixelReader` and `PixelWriter`, but they are not important here.

The stylesheet attached to the scene can be switched at runtime. How do I make the image change color when the stylesheet is changed?

The only thing that I thought would make sense is to create a new JavaFX CSS property (e.g. `-image-color: theme-image-color;`), but it doesn't seem possible to add this in just like this.

### Edit

Looks like I should also include the `changeImageColor()` method.

```
public static final WritableImage changeImageColor(Image image, Color newColor)
{
    if (image == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot change the color of a null image.");

    WritableImage newImage = new WritableImage((int) image.getWidth(), (int) image.getHeight());
    PixelWriter writer = newImage.getPixelWriter();
    PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();

    for (int readY = 0; readY < image.getHeight(); readY++)
    {
        for (int readX = 0; readX < image.getWidth(); readX++)
        {
            Color color = reader.getColor(readX, readY);
            if (color.getOpacity() > 0)
            {
                writer.setColor(readX, readY, newColor);
            }
        }
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: How you convert the image (If the image becomes filled with the color completely, go for a `Rectangle` instead)? Do you extract a channel (if so can there only be R, G or B?)? Do you use the desired color adjusted with the given brightness?

Comment: @fabian The method is probably not important. But anyway, I checked the color of each pixel to see it has non-zero opacity, and change it to the specified color. The return value is a `WritableImage` that is casted into `Image`.

Comment: The method is important since some effects can be achieved via blend modes. A threshold afaik cannot be achieved though.